# Windows 10 won't install - issues with disk

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation, dualboot

First of all forgive me if the title or anything bellow is vague. I'm a professional programmer far from being a sysadmin and anything Windows-related is a great mystery for me. Also sorry for infodump, as I don't know which information is relevant.

**Setup**

I have a computer that I bought 10-11 years ago and have been swapping parts since. The only exception are discs which I "just add". Until today I had 4 HDD and 1 SSD. System is in UEFI mode

**The background**

I have a machine with dual-boot: Ubuntu 18.10 (I know, I know, I'll upgrade once 20.04 is out) for almost everything and Windows 10 for fun and games. However W10 has been giving me problems recently - being very slow, many programs just suddenly are stopping working and there is BSOD every two days on average. So what else to do, then to reinstall it right? Especially that I've discovered it's installed on HDD despite having place for it on my SSD.

**The problems**

First issue was with the installation. Windows straight up refused to install itself on SSD with cryptic message `We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one` and then something about more info being in journal files (where they are nor how to read them I don't know, but more about that later). So the first solution was to run `diskpart` and run `clean` on disk.

Then I've ordered 2nd SSD, because I'm not going to wipe disk that also has Linux on it. Inserted it, run the installation. Same problem. So `diskpart`, `clean` and the problem is still there.

I've then disconnected all other discs apart from the new SSD (I vaguely remembered it working a few years ago with W8 or W7 on a different motherboard) and it worked. System installed correctly. So then I've reconnected all other discs, booted into Ubuntu, updated grub. Grub detected new windows installation so I've rebooted and selected the new Windows and was imminently greeted with `Device <address> cannot be found` (old W10 and Ubuntu still work fine).

Then I've decided to try looking at that journal file, meaning try to fail the installation again (which it did) and also try swapping some SATA cables, but my USB with Windows 10 got formatted somewhere along the way.

Either way - I want to know what's going on and how can I make Windows install exactly where I want it to install (just like Ubuntu) and **not** wipe any data outside the partition I want it to install on.

Comment: How you boot both Windows & Linux UEFI or BIOS is then how it  installs. So be sure to boot in UEFI mode. And Windows in UEFI mode only installs to gpt partitioned drives. If blank drive it should not complain. It normally wants to install to default drive in UEFI. So often better to disable in UEFI or physically disconnect all other drives. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions

Comment: I've went through that once again and it worked. I'm writing this from my new installation. Unfortunately after everything went well I moved files from the old windows to the new one, and it decided to remove them all. I hate that system. Anyway - thanks for your comment.